# Replacement character \uFFFD while GetWindowText (C code)

Tags: c, string, unicode

I'm getting Spotify's window title for my Now Playing plugin with function:

```
GetWindowText(spotify_window_handle, title, title_length)
```

but output contain Replacement character \uFFFD.

```
Ex. Spotify - Killswitch Engage � One Last Sunset
```

How to replace � with - in C?

Below full code:

```
char* spotify_title(int window_handle)
{
    int title_length = GetWindowTextLength(window_handle);
        if(title_length != 0)
        {
            char* title;
            title = (char*)malloc((++title_length) * sizeof *title );
            if(title != NULL)
            {
                GetWindowText(window_handle, title, title_length);
                if(strcmp(title, "Spotify") != 0)
            {
                return title;
            }
            else
            {
                return "Spotify is not playing anything right now. Type !botnext command to restart playback.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("PLUGIN: Unable to allocate memory for title\n");
        }
        free(title);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("PLUGIN: Unable to get Spotify window title\n");
    }
}
// End of Spotify get title function
```

Comment: How is `title` declared?

Comment: I've pasted full function

Answer (score 1):

The replacement character is used during Unicode->Ansi conversions.  Without seeing how `title` is actually declared (is it using `char` or `wchar_t`?), my guess is that you are calling the Ansi version of `GetWindowText()` (aka `GetWindowTextA()`) and the window title contains a Unicode character that cannot be represented in your OS's default Ansi locale, so `GetWindowTextA()` replaces that character when converting the window text to Ansi for output.  Keep in mind that Windows is actually a Unicode-based OS, so you should use the Unicode version of `GetWindowText()` (aka `GetWindowTextW()`) instead, eg:

```
WCHAR title[256];
int title_length = 256;
GetWindowTextW(spotify_window_handle, title, title_length);
```

Or:

```
int title_length = GetWindowTextLengthW(spotify_window_handle);
LPWSTR title = (LPWSTR) malloc((title_length+1) * sizeof(WCHAR));
GetWindowTextW(spotify_window_handle, title, title_length+1);
...
free(title);
```

Or at least make sure your project is configured to compile for Unicode so that `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` are defined during compiling.  That will make `GetWindowText()` map to `GetWindowTextW()` instead of `GetWindowTextA()`.  You will then have to use `TCHAR` for your `title` buffer, eg:

```
TCHAR title[256];
int title_length = 256;
GetWindowText(spotify_window_handle, title, title_length);
```

Or:

```
int title_length = GetWindowTextLength(spotify_window_handle);
LPTSTR title = (LPTSTR) malloc((title_length+1) * sizeof(TCHAR));
GetWindowText(spotify_window_handle, title, title_length+1);
...
free(title);
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on if you are using Unicode or not.  Since you say \uFFFD you are most likely in Unicode so

```
   WCHAR *wp; 

   while ((wp= wcschr(title, '\uFFFD'))!=NULL) {
       *wp= L'-';
   }
```

Comment: with a char *title, how can there be a 16bit \xFFFD in it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the strings are arrays of `wchar_t`:

```
wchar_t * p = wcschr(title, `\uFFFD`);
if (p)
  *p = `\u002D`;
```